# Retrieving the value of a key by the hash of the key in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the below dictionary:

```
>>> dict1={'a':1,'b':2}
>>>
>>>
>>> dict1['a']
1
>>>
```

Q: Is there a way to retrieve the value of key (in the above dictionary), using the hash value of the key?
If I print `'a'.__hash__` , I get:

```
>>> print 'a'.__hash__
<method-wrapper '__hash__' of str object at 0x00000000021AA0F8>
>>>
```

Q2: Why not do a key lookup directly rather than converting the key to a hash value and then do the lookup? I read that using hash makes it faster.

Comment: There is not necessary a one-to-one mapping between the hash and the key, it depends on the implementation and on the key.  Of course Python manages to do the lookup, and I suggest you download the C source and read `Objects/dictnotes.txt`  and `Objects/dictobject.c`.  Then you will probably decide it is better to let Python do it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to retrieve the value using hash by yourself, Python dict do that for you. Python dict use hash internally.

from https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

> A mapping object maps hashable values to arbitrary objects. Mappings
>   are mutable objects. There is currently only one standard mapping
>   type, the dictionary.

Comment: i understand what you say, but i need to know if there is a way to get the value of a key(in a dict) using the hash of the key ?